# violinplot style histogram in plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a plot with several data points that I would like to keep as it is.

One of the data point is 'better', because it does not only come with a value but also a probability assigned to it.

I would like to show that probability by plotting the normal data points, and for the one with the measured PDF show a violinplot.

So far I've done this with a scatter plot over plotted which looks somewhat like this (in an MWE):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



def plot():
    x = np.linspace(0,20,20)
    data =  x + np.random.rand(len(x))
    y =  2*x
    histo = np.array([1,2,3,10,20,10,3,1])
    y_better = np.array([9.5,9.8,10,11.5,12,13,15,16])

    ax = plt.subplot()
    ax.plot(x,data,'o')
    ax.scatter(np.ones_like(histo)*x[10],y_better,c=histo,norm=matplotlib.colors.LogNorm(),s=100)
    plt.show()

plot()
```

which looks like this:

[image]

While this works, and transports the message - but doesn't look too cool.

Following the suggestion by @￼jadsq, I discovered [violinplots](https://matplotlib.org/examples/statistics/violinplot_demo.html), which look exactly like what I want!

I now have the problem that the violinplot function assumes data and then conveniently draws the PDF. In my case I already have a measured PDF (which is what I want to plot). How could I make a plot that looks like the violin plot, but with my PDF (so without the estimation)?

Comment: you might also consider a `seaborn` `swarmplot`: https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.swarmplot.html#seaborn.swarmplot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me it looks like a way of indicating error bars on your point so you could maybe try representing it with a [box plot](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/statistics/boxplot_vs_violin.html#sphx-glr-gallery-statistics-boxplot-vs-violin-py).

Regarding the color map: just add `cmap='inferno'` in the scatter call,like so :

```
ax.scatter(np.ones_like(histo)*x[10],y_better,c=histo,norm=matplotlib.colors.LogNorm(),s=100,cmap='inferno')
```

Comment: Thanks. 
Following your suggestion of box plots, I discoverd the Violin ones, which look amazing. Now I still have a problem and have updated my question!